# enter records in column locaion_new based on value of column location_old

Tags: sql

i.e when location_old='r-0000' then location_new='r-0280' otherwise for anyother value of location_old the corresponding value of location_new be same.

```
select year, month, amount, account, location_old, costcentre_old, costcentre_new,
       'location_new'= case when location_old='r-0000' then 'r-0280'
                            else 'loation_old'
                       end
from asign3;
```

Comment: And what is the issue with your query?  Also, tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide the details @Gordon Linoff asked for. In additon a few sample rows of your database table are needed. Without this additional question I will suggest the mods to close this question. For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the single quotes from the identifiers. They should only be used for string literals. And unless you're using SQL Server, the syntax for an aliased column is `<expression> [AS] <alias>` not `<alias> = <expression>`. But as SQL Server also understands the latter, I'd recommend to use the latter at any rate.

```
SELECT year,
       month,
       amount,
       account,
       location_old,
       costcentre_old,
       costcentre_new,
       CASE
         WHEN location_old = 'r-0000' THEN
           'r-0280'
         ELSE
           location_old
       END location_new
       FROM asign3;
```